# VB.NET code highlighting problem resurging

Tags: support, code-formatting

There is a code syntax highlighting problem which had been fixed a long time ago, but for the last couple of weeks appears again. Usually it would automatically detect that the code sample is VB.NET (because of `vb.net` tag I think) and format it properly. In the last weeks I have to add the markup `<!-- language-all: lang-vb -->` for my code samples to display properly.

For example, if you look at my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690639/mysql-and-asp-net-vb-issue-with-time-automatically-being-added-to-date-field/) you can see that code is highlighted properly, because I added the markup tag to specify that the language is VB. But if you remove the hint, then it doesn't recognize VB (comments aren't displayed properly).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works, but it looks like the [mysql] tag is picked up first for syntax highlighting since it appears first in the question's tag list. Hence the highlighting issue for your answer. Not entirely sure if this *can* be fixed, since the highlighter doesn't really intelligently examine the code - it just looks for some keywords, so it can't tell SQL apart from VB or anything else.

Comment: Anna's right, the [mysql] and [vb.net] tags are fighting, and the SQL syntax hint is winning. Manually specifying it works, because that overrides the tag's default language hint. So this is not the same problem as before that is resurging, it's an entirely different problem. I can't think of a good way to fix it, since SQL and VB.NET code *should* be formatted differently. This is why we allow manually specifying the syntax hinting, so I'd say you've done the right thing.

Comment: Use two quotes in a vb.net snippet, `'' like this`.

Comment: @CodyGray: I think you're right, I can see that questions tagged only `vb.net` are OK, but it seemed to me that even when mixing tags, VB.NET code was correctly detected before, but not anymore (it happens with other tags not just mysql).

Comment: @UphillLuge: Might as well add the language hint...

Comment: Seconding what @AnnaLear has said - both [tag:mysql] and [tag:vb.net] have tag-level syntax highlighting hints set, which override the highlighter's normal "figure it out" mode.  Because [tag:mysql] is the more prominent tag, it's going to win.  You'll have to add the hint in this case.