# VB.NET tag needs to have ‘lang-vb.net’ syntax highlighter set as default

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, tags

When I [manually specify the language](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) of a code block as VB.NET like this:

```
<!-- language: vbnet -->

    theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

```
theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

the code is not highlighted. But this variation works:

```
<!-- language: lang-vbnet -->

    theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

```vbnet
theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

I get the same results for both versions when I replace `vbnet` with `vb.net`:

```
<!-- language: vb.net -->

    theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

```
theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

```
<!-- language: lang-vb.net -->

    theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

```vb
theNodeList.Cast(Of XmlNode)()
```

In the first version, the language is specified through the tag. In the second version, it's specified through the syntax highlighting parser name. The problem is that the [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) tag isn't automatically setting the correct parser for (unlike most other language tags). [This old comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting#comment195638_72163) indicates that a diamond moderator has the power to fix this. Or perhaps the parser is correctly set for the tag, but there's a bug in Stack Overflow with tags with periods in their names.

The tags on a question shouldn't affect whether this problem appears, since the comment should override all tags. That makes this question different from [VB.NET code highlighting problem resurging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125919/184047), where there were multiple tags on a question, and a code block with no comment was being assigned the wrong default language.

Comment: The funny thing is that big PHP frameworks (like Symfony or cakePHP) links to PHP and vbnet, the language tag, does not even link to vbnet  xD

Comment: According to the source code of prettify, we only have `vb` and `vbs`, no `vbnet`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Ah. I tried `vbnet` because that's Vim's name for its VB.NET syntax highlighter, and then I saw it seem to work. But it looks like even `lang-vbfoo` highlights as Visual Basic - the suffix is ignored. Still, using the `vb` highlighter for [tag:vb.net] is better than no highlighting at all.

Comment: FWIW, highlighting is correctly configured for [tag:vb.net]. If there are multiple language tags, you'll need to set the highlight explicitly, which is described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify

Comment: @Shog9 I don’t see how highlighting is correctly configured. If I [create a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the [tag:vb.net] tag and paste some code like `Call MyFun` into it, the code is not highlighted at all. The code *should* be highlighted using the `vb` highlighter, which is the closest approximation for vb.net we have, and better than nothing. You can see that the code looks better when you manually add `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` – but you shouldn’t have to manually add that; the [tag:vb.net] tag should do that for you.

Comment: Can you give me an example of it not working, @Rory? [Looks right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270132/on-error-go-to-the-next-desired-operation-instead-of-next-line).

Comment: @Shog9 It looks like I was confusing the unknown-language highlighting with the `lang-vb` highlighting. In the question above, with the (nonexistent) `lang-vb.net` parser, `Cast` and `Of XmlNode` are colored blue; I assumed that was how they were supposed to be highlighted. But now I see that with the `lang-vb` parser, they are not highlighted; instead, keywords like `Call` are highlighted in dark blue. So [tag:vb.net] does have highlighting, it just doesn’t highlight things I thought it would.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for this behavior is simple: if it starts with `lang-` then it uses that language.

Otherwise it uses the assigned highlighting for THAT tag.

So:

- `vbnet` tries to use the highlighting of the tag [vbnet](/questions/tagged/vbnet) (which does not exist)
- `lang-vbnet` uses the vbnet highlighting. For the list of aviable langs see [here](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#langs)
- `vb.net` uses the highlighting of [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) which was assigned to vbnet. (I hope. If not, request it here on meta as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).)

Not a bug IMHO.

Comment: Also note that the tag based selection does not work if there are incompatible tags like [tag:sql] and [tag:vb.net].

Comment: The `vb.net` tag is missing its assignation to `lang-vbnet`. `<!-- language: vb.net -->` doesn't work. That's what I meant by "I get the same results for both versions when I replace `vbnet` with `vb.net`." So there *is* a problem here. Maybe "bug" is the wrong term for this type of problem, but the `vb.net` tag is missing its link to the `lang-vbnet` parser.

Comment: Ok, this is a different thing. Maybe [meta-tag:feature-request] would be better than [meta-tag:bug]?

Comment: Okay, I changed the tag to [tag:feature-request].